# How to add samples in Asset Store?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, sample

I cannot add an instance to my asset in the Asset Store. I looked at the documentation but couldn't succeed. Where am I making a mistake?

[image]

```
MyPackage
  ├── package.json
  └── Samples~
        ├── StarterAssets
```

#### `package.json`

```
{
    "samples": [
        {
            "displayName": "StarterAssets Example Scenes",
            "description": "Contains demo scenes with StarterAssets.",
            "path": "Samples~/StarterAssets"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, might want to include more information, such as any error/warning logs within your unity engine. Though, I would recommend you post your questions here instead: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. When I moved the project from the `Plugins` folder to the `Packages` folder, samples started to appear.